# Populate list in POCO using subselect - LINQ to entites

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, poco

I am trying to create a list of POCOs from my database.  The POCO class has a `List<int>` property which I want to populate like so:

```cs
public List<Pocos.MyTable> GetData()
{
    using (EFContext c = new EFContext())
    {
        var query = from t in c.MyTable
                    select new Pocos.MyTable()
                    {
                        MyId = t.MyId,
                        MyField = t.MyField,
                        MyRelationIds = t.MyRelations.Select(mr => mr.MyRelationId).ToList()
                    };

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting the "this method cannot be translated into a store expression" on the `ToList()`in the query.  Can I do this nicely here, or do I have to do lots of subsequent queries to populate the `MyRelationIds` property?

Comment: Do you have a problem with using `MyRelations` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code and description I got, that if try to just use `MyRelations`, it is not loaded. And then you try to populeta `MyRelationsIds` during query. There are two ways to solve this. I personally prefer the first one:

1. Replace your `MyRelations` property with `public virtual List<Relation> MyRelations`. Virtual is a convention, after which EF will create a proxy, that will act as a lazy property. I.e. it will be loaded as soon as you touch it.
2. Another way is to use eager loading, with it you don't have to change the signature.
   Just use `Include` method, to tell EF which props do you want to load eagerly.
   See that `.Include("MyRelations")` it tell, that MyRelations must be loaded during this query. So you can use them later. And if you want to have only ids of relations, then you should first materialize your objects and then do mapping (note `AsEnumerable()`)

   ```
   using (EFContext c = new EFContext())
   {
       var query = from t in c.MyTable.Include("MyRelations").AsEnumerable()
       select new Pocos.MyTable()
       {
           MyId = t.MyId,
           MyField = t.MyField,
           MyRelationIds = t.MyRelations.Select(mr => mr.MyRelationId).ToList()
       };

       return query.ToList();
    }
   ```

Comment: @errorstacks thanks for help with the code, I was messing with it for past 5 minutes :) It seems, there is some conflict between list and code markups.

Comment: Oh man, that's it?  Its not loaded?  I just assumed the lazy loading would kick in and make sure that relation is loaded.  I just threw in your second suggestion (as its a quick win), and it works.  I guess I need to read up more on this stuff.. :|

Answer (score 0):

Did you try remove the ".ToList()" from the line:

```
MyRelationIds = t.MyRelations.Select(mr => mr.MyRelationId).ToList()
```

so it looks like this:

```
MyRelationIds = t.MyRelations.Select(mr => mr.MyRelationId)
```

?

Comment: This gives me `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`